# Customize menu on right click for entire row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm working to make the right click as my customize menu to display using the mouse. Here is my code:

```
click: function (event) {
                var eventResult = this.get('tableView').clickRow(event, this.get('object'));
                if (eventResult !== false) {
                    this.get('element').focus();
                    $('.content-row').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var parentId = $(this).closest('tr').prop('id');
                        alert(parentId);
                        $('.managed-object-action-menu').click();
                    });
                }
                return eventResult;
            },
```

If I'm using the `.managed-object-action-menu`, it will affect for entire rows in the table. But i need only to display customize menu for the active row.

[image]

I'm new to the `Ember` and `jQuery`.

Comment: I am not able to understand. can you give some screenshots?

Comment: @Arulraj I have edited with screenshot. Please see and suggest

Comment: How do you distinguish an active row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:
Fetch the Parent element Id with children class value

```
click: function (event) {
    var eventResult = this.get('tableView').clickRow(event, this.get('object'));
    if (eventResult !== false) {
        this.get('element').focus();
        $('.content-row').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var parentId = $(this).closest('tr').prop('id');
            $('#'+parentId).find( ".managed-object-action-menu" ).click();
        });
    }
    return eventResult;
},
```

Try it

Comment: I would recommend against using the `id` of an element, and just use the element directly. Lots of elements are given ids in Ember, but that’s an implementation detail and shouldn’t be relied on.